# Marpa parser can't seem to cope with optional first symbol?

Tags: perl, marpa

I've been getting to grips with the Marpa parser and encountered a problem when the first symbol is optional. Here's an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dump;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({source  => \<<'END_OF_GRAMMAR'});
:start ::= Rule
Rule ::= <optional a> 'X'
<optional a> ~ a *
a ~ 'a'
END_OF_GRAMMAR

my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({grammar => $grammar});
dd $recce->read(\"X");
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in SLIF parse: No lexemes accepted at line 1, column 1
* String before error:
* The error was at line 1, column 1, and at character 0x0058 'X', ...
* here: X
Marpa::R2 exception at small.pl line 20
 at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Marpa/R2.pm line 126
        Marpa::R2::exception('Error in SLIF parse: No lexemes accepted at line 1, column 1\x{a}...') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Marpa/R2/Scanless.pm line 1545
        Marpa::R2::Scanless::R::read_problem('Marpa::R2::Scanless::R=ARRAY(0x95cbfd0)', 'no lexemes accepted') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Marpa/R2/Scanless.pm line 1345
        Marpa::R2::Scanless::R::resume('Marpa::R2::Scanless::R=ARRAY(0x95cbfd0)', 0, -1) called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Marpa/R2/Scanless.pm line 926
        Marpa::R2::Scanless::R::read('Marpa::R2::Scanless::R=ARRAY(0x95cbfd0)', 'SCALAR(0x95aeb1c)') called at small.pl line 20
```

Perl version 5.14.2  (debian wheezy)
Marpa version 2.068000

(I see there's a brand new Marpa 2.069 that I haven't tried yet)

Is this something I'm doing wrong in my grammar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Marpa Scanless, your grammar has two levels: The main, high-level grammar where you can attribute actions and such, and the low-level lexing grammar. They are executed independently (which is expected if you have used traditional parser/lexers, but is very confusing when you come from regexes to Marpa).

Now on the low level grammar, Marpa recognizes your input as a single `X`, not “zero `a`s and then an `X`”. However, the high-level grammar *requires* the `optional a` symbol to be present.

There best way around that is to make the `a` optional in the high-level grammar:

```
<optional a> ::= <many a>
<optional a> ::=  # empty

<many a> ~ a*  # would work the same here with "a+"
a ~ 'a'
```

Comment: amon has it right.  A lexeme can never be zero length, so even if you use a*, it will have the effect of a+.  I considered banning lexemes that match at zero-length, but it's often very convenient to write the lexeme that way.

Comment: +1: Thanks for that. I overlooked that G0/G1 rule distinction here. Your modification worked for my example.

Comment: @JeffreyKegler: BTW when I was preparing my example, I accidentally wrote the last G0 rule as `a ~ a`. I realise this can't work but I got a SEGV error rather than a message. Would you expect this?

Comment: @Adrian: No, I would not expect it.  It's a bug.  I am able to duplicate it and am working on it now.

Comment: @Adrian: Bug fixed in Marpa-R2 2.069_002, now on CPAN.  The problem was that a quantified rule with an unproductive symbol (one that never nulled or produced terminals) resulted in a SEGV instead of an error message.  Marpa::R2 now produces an appropriate error message.  Thanks!